# Installing Orfeo tool box with QGIS?

Tags: installation, orfeo-toolbox

I have installed QGIS and OTB according to instructions (Win 8, 64 bit) . I have set the paths in the "Orfeo Tool Box menu". See attached.
I get a message "Wrong value for parameter "Msys value".
I built empty directories of "Msys" in QGIS, and now the message doesn't appear, but there is no OTB menu in the Toolbox pulldown

[image],

Comment: Try using `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\orfeotoolbox\applications` for the _OTB applications folder_.

Comment: See my [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15927/does-anyone-know-how-to-install-the-orfeo-toolbox-in-qgis) to a question that covers this error message and how to fix it.