# orfeo toolbox in Qgis 2.18.13 windows 7 32 bit

Tags: orfeo-toolbox

I installed the orfeo toolbox in Qgis but got this error.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] your question to contain the error message text **as text** , in the body of the question.

Comment: See my [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15927/does-anyone-know-how-to-install-the-orfeo-toolbox-in-qgis) to a question that covers this error message and how to fix it.