# Orfeo Toolbox on Mac

Tags: mac, orfeo-toolbox, image-segmentation

I managed to install OTB 8.0.1 in QGIS 3.22 on Mac using a comment on this community. However, the plugin is not working when I try to use "Segmentation". The process tells something like this:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libOTBCommandLine-8.0.1.dylib Referenced 
from: /Applications/OTB/OTB-8.0.1-Darwin64/bin/otbApplicationLauncherCommandLine
Reason: image not found
```

Does my image have a problem or did I install OTB wrongly?

Comment: How did you proceed, could you link the post that helped you with the installation process ?
Also, it may be due to incompatibilities with newest hardware. Is your Mac Intel based, or M1 / ARM ?

Comment: Hi there! My Mac is Intel based. The post that helped me was made by JDahlgreen and EcologyTom on 9th July 2021.https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15927/installing-the-orfeo-toolbox-in-qgis

Comment: Did you activate the OTB plugin in the extension parameters ? Follow the best answer (not the green checked one) of the post you linked here. It is a built-in plugin you need to enable, similarly to GRASS

Comment: But if you did activate it, I'd say (from your error message) that the path may be wrong. You need to double check that, following the docs on the official OTB website. Else you should ask your question on the official otb forum https://forum.orfeo-toolbox.org

Answer (score 1):

I didn't manage to use OTB on Mac. After all trials, I made a Windows installation on my Mac. OTB is working perfectly here!